# Detect Exception on RabbitMq connection

Tags: spring-integration, spring-rabbit, spring-integration-amqp

Using spring integration to transfer message from RabbitMQ to MQ works well.

If i stop the RabbitMQ server, then we have an error on log files :

```
ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Node was put into maintenance mode, class-id=0, method-id=0)
```

How can we intercept this exception ?

This works fine when adding `ExceptionListener` on jms `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`

Following the configuration of beans:

```
<bean id="connectionAmqpFactorySrc" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
    <property name="automaticRecoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="networkRecoveryInterval" value="10000"/>
</bean>

<rabbit:connection-factory  id="rabbitConnectionFactory" connection-factory="connectionAmqpFactorySrc"
    username="guest" 
    password="guest" 
    addresses="XX.XX.XX.XX"
    cache-mode="CONNECTION" 
    virtual-host="/"  
    shuffle-addresses="true" />


<bean id="fixedBackOffRabbitMQ" class="org.springframework.util.backoff.FixedBackOff">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="10000" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="3" />
</bean>
    
<bean id="myListener" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="rabbitConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="queueNames" value="MyQueue" />
    <property name="recoveryBackOff" ref="fixedBackOffRabbitMQ"/>
    <property name="channelTransacted" value="true"></property>
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="errorHandler"></property>
</bean>
    
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter   channel="channelRmqMQ" 
        id="inboundChannelAdapter" 
        auto-startup="true" listener-container="myListener" error-channel="processChannel1" />
```

**EDIT1**

As you advised me I use the definition of a bean like that :

```
<bean id="listeners" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="connectionAmqpListener" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="rabbitConnectionFactory"  class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="connectionAmqpFactorySrc"/>
    <property name="username" value="guest"/>
    <property name="password" value="guest"/>
    <property name="addresses" value="XX.XX.XX.XX"/>
    <property name="cacheMode" value="CONNECTION"/>
    <property name="virtualHost" value="/"/>
    <property name="shuffleAddresses" value="true"/>
    <property name="connectionListeners" ref="listeners"/>
</bean>
```

With the `ConnectionAmqpListener.java`

```
public class ConnectionAmqpListener implements ConnectionListener {
    
    private final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ConnectionAmqpListener.class);
    
    public ConnectionAmqpListener() {
        super();
    }
    
    public void onCreate(Connection connection) {
        System.out.println("Open connection");
    }
    
    public void onClose(Connection connection) {
        System.out.println("Connection is closed");
    }
    
    public void onShutDown(ShutdownSignalException signal) {
        System.out.println("Connection is shutdown");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

This works fine, when i stop the broker , the method `onShutDown` is called.

But if i restart my process (with the broker down) i do not have any message in the log file and the process is stopped.

Do you have any recommandations on how to get informations if the connection fails?

**END EDIT1**

Thanks for your help

Regards,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

See `ConnectionFactory`:

```
void addConnectionListener(ConnectionListener listener)
```

That callback has this hook:

```
/**
 * Called when a connection is force closed.
 * @param signal the shut down signal.
 * @since 2.0
 */
default void onShutDown(ShutdownSignalException signal) {
}
```

Comment: You cannot. Use `<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"/>` with an appropriate properties setting, including the mentioned `connectionListeners` or switch to Java & Annotation configuration.

Comment: Sorry i remove my previous comment because i found how to do it. Adding this block i catch the exception.

`<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
     <property name="targetObject" ref="rabbitConnectionFactory" />
     <property name="targetMethod" value="addConnectionListener" />
     <property name="arguments" ref="connectionAmqpListener" />
</bean>` 

But with this syntax when i relaunch my process on the RabbitMQ down i don't get any error? Do you think i need to use your method? or addind an other listener?